# What is PM2 namespace?

Tags: node.js, namespaces, queue, pm2, worker

I have tens of processes and all of them have 'default' as their namespace.

When I run `pm2 show processid` it returns:

```
│ status            │ online                                      │
│ name              │ Email Worker 1                              │
│ namespace         │ default                                     │
│ version           │ N/A                                         │
│ restarts          │ 2                                           │
│ uptime            │ 21h                                         │
│ script path       │ /bin/bash
```

But I don't know what the namespace is and how to change/use it. I looked at the [official documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) but still not found any info about it?

Is it like a group of processes? But how to set and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace is a grouping of processes running on pm2.

For more information on how to use namespace, see the

```
pm2 start [processName] --name [name] --namespace [namespace]
```

You can run it with the command in .

The basic method of utilization is
You can view logs from the same group at once.

Usually when viewing pm2 logs

```
pm2 log [name]
```

You can see it as

If you're using a namespace to group

```
pm2 log [namespace]
```

allows you to view the logs for that group at once.

You can also use that namespace to start/end.

```
pm2 start [namespace]
pm2 stop [namespace]
pm2 restart [namespace]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You can define a namespace for processes in ecosystem files.

Then, you can use namespace in pm2 command, like this:

```
pm2 start myNamespace

pm2 restart myNamespace
```

etc.

If namespace exists, PM2 will apply command to all menber of namespace.

Answer (score -2):

You can set an application name with --name

```
pm2 start app.js --name "my-app"
```

Later you can use this name to start/stop/restart your application.